# QAM Amplitude Levels

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, dsp-core

I'm working on a project to stream video between 2fpgas by using QAM. While mapping symbols with different amplitude pulses(PAM) a question popped up in my mind. In real life how does communicating wireless devices know which amplitude levels to agree on for digitally modulating-demodulating bitstreams? Is there a standard for that?

Answer (score 2):

> n real life how does communicating wireless devices know which amplitude levels to agree on for digitally modulating-demodulating bitstreams?

You can't "agree" on levels, since the received amplitude depends on the attenuation on the channel, and that depends on distance and a lot of other factors.

So, your receiver depends on detecting something that it knows the *right* amplitude (or power) of – for example, a preamble, or an *average* squared symbol, or something like that.

How that is done depends on the system you look at – generally, this is part of the synchronization and equalization efforts every system has to make. And it really differs! For example, some continuously transmitting system will not insert any specific symbols for that, but depend on the receiver doing statistics. Others have a "silence" period followed by known symbols; other systems are packetized and depend on preambles with specific autocorrelation properties (but not necessarily 100% defined content). Other systems depend on a pilot tone, and there's many more options.

Comment: Just a quick comment to add that the receiver may also do AGC.

Comment: there should be some sort of standard otherwise how all digital devices that communicates with QAM will understand each other. I'm really really confused

Comment: @BahattinBademci there is more to it than device A uses QAM and device B uses QAM so they will be able to understand each other, that is not true. The above answer explains that parts of the rx chain are system dependent. For example, one system might be a wideband wireless system and the other might be a cabled system but both use QAM as the modulation. This does not mean that you can just interchange the receivers and expect good results

Comment: of course there is more to it. I know that but apart from this it is essentially how you are packing your bits to transmit which is QAM. this is how it starts right? You are basically deciding like for example 0010 will be 0.5V 1000 will be 1.45V and if you dont know how you packed there is no point what method you are using in the receiver cause you dont know what the incoming signal means.

Comment: no. That's not how it starts. Nobody standardizes on a specific voltage set: You always have to decide based on a reference signal from the transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

The important part is that the symbol constellation is agreed upon between transmitter and receiver. The received amplitude will most likely randomly fluctuate over time, but eventually the receiver processing gets to a point where it needs to generate symbol estimates. For example, look at the transmission of a single symbol of 16 QAM. Lets say that the red symbol is transmitted.

[image]

The transmitter puts some gain on the signal and puts it out on the channel. At the other side, the receiver will do a bunch of processing that might be system dependent (equalization and synchronization for example) before it can get to a point where a symbol estimate can be made. At this point, you might have something that looks like this:

[image]

The scale of the symbols is different now. But this is just a scaling that can be undone to match the agreed upon constellation. So before the receiver does the symbol estimates it does the scaling to match.

[image]

Comment: and my question is that what are the amplitude values or range of values that decides which symbol it's at the end?

Comment: @BahattinBademci the receiver is totally free to scale the receive signal. in the QAM16 example, it only matters that you make a 4×4 grid. There's no absolute level necessary anywhere.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes it's not absolute value but it's a range. so how receiver decides for example which range is 0101? it just can not be that the receiver does whatever it wants.

Comment: it doesn't do what it wants. It gets a reference from its received signal, and adjusts the signal amplification (to fit its arbitrarily chosen decision boundaries) or adjusts the  decision boundaries (to fit the unpredictably attenuated signal). No absolute levels or ranges *can* be involved anywhere. Hence, no standard needs to specify absolute ranges, it just needs to say "you use 16-QAM, and the transmitter sends a reference symbol, and then it's your responsibility as receiver to decide correctly"

Comment: @BahattinBademci your reasoning about using voltages to decide on the bits is wrong, I'm not sure where you got that from but I've never heard of that (could you include a reference for that?). If you want to think in terms of received signal levels, the part that will matter is the ratio between the received signal power and the receiver noise power. A system will have a minimum SNR requirement (link budget)

Comment: @Engineer I'd say internet for that as I could not find good resource to understand how it works. Can you please share link, book or anything that explains how QAM works?

Comment: @BahattinBademci Any "normal" digital comms textbook will tell you that the receiver will make decisions based on the symbols it receives, and you have realize these symbols or the decision boundaries are adjusted by the receiver, because nobody can know the channel's attenuation. Really, the idea that transmitter and receiver have the same idea of what a "volt" is doesn't even work, and you seem to be still forgetting that your signal suffers a random attenuation on the channel that your receiver has to compensate for its purpose, anyway.

Comment: @BahattinBademci any digital comms book, books by Proakis or Haykin are popular. They would explain the concepts and not a specific protocol, but I think what you’re asking is independent of protocol. Do you understand what was mentioned about decision boundaries in the other comment? That is what I was trying to show.

Comment: @Engineer now I understand it's not 'voltage to bits' but still do not know how the receiver decides. Does the receiver at first receive number of symbols and then make calculations on a chunk and decides what the bitstreams are?

Comment: @BahattinBademci Do you understand the concept of decision regions? These scale as the symbol energies scale. Very often you'll see things shown in terms of unit average power (like my first and last picture), but there is no reason you can't scale. The symbol to bit mapping is the inverse of the bit to symbol mapping that you used (gray code or whatever you used)

Comment: @Engineer Am I wrong with mixing PAM and QAM?